# NextCloud Docker File Upload Not Working Error 504?

Tags: docker, file, upload, nextcloud

I am using NextCloud Docker Image (Insecure docker-compose example) with a NGINX Reverse Proxy and I can't seem to upload a file greater than 1gb, if I try to it will give me the 504 Could not reassemble chunks error message

Here is my nginx.conf for Reverse Proxy
https://paste.fastermc.xyz/enapajiler.nginx

Here is my nginx.conf for NextCloud
https://paste.fastermc.xyz/namehowezo.nginx

Here is my php.ini for NextCloud
https://paste.fastermc.xyz/omegunohoy.coffeescript

Here is my www.conf for NextCloud
https://paste.fastermc.xyz/akecoqugob.pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to add this to nginx proxy config file

```
location / {
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 64;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        add_header Front-End-Https on;
        proxy_pass http(s)://<your NextCloud ip and port>;
    }
```

Also add client_max_body 10G; to NextCloud nginx.conf and post_max_size = 10G in php.ini

Comment: Adding this (minus the last two lines as that caused a warning in Firefox about this being a self-signed certificate) my NC URL now opens a "Welcome to OpenResty!" page. I'm using Nginx Proxy Manager though.